# cosume a WCF windows service from another PC

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have created a WCF service and hosted it in a windows service. Testing this service with visual studio works fine and I can consume it. Now I have installed the service on a PC (called PC1) and using another PC (called PC2) I wish to be able to discover it and consume it. I imagine that I will have to modify the app.config file to achieve this.

Here is my current app.config, what do I need to modify to get this to work from other networked computers? I'm guessing the base address is a start?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>      
  <service name="WcfAVOLibrary.AVOs">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="WcfAVOLibrary.IAVOs">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfAVOLibrary/AVOs/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

oh and i'm running .Net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

- (if the web service is not implemented, I recommend this link 
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0)

You should try to modify the web.config in this place:

```
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.2/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfAVOLibrary/AVOs/" />
  </baseAddresses>
```

where 192.168.1.2 is your current ip, or localhost works too, it would see like this:

```
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfAVOLibrary/AVOs/" />
  </baseAddresses>
```

Comment: this is a windows service and not a web service

Answer (score 0):

At first place, change localhost by pc1 on base address, like

`http://pc1:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfAVOLibrary/AVOs/`

After it, try to open the base address url from browser on pc2 (yes, never mind that it  is win. service - this is your service url and should be accessible). It should be ok, you need not to continue before you get it work.

When it done - review client's config to match service address.

Comment: I tried the address on another PC and could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue. Added inbound rule to open the port 8733 in Windows Firewall. It worked!